# Jacoco shows All branches covered with Green mark but shows < 100% in Missed branches. What is wrong here?

Tags: kotlin, code-coverage, jacoco

I have a simple `isSubClass` function which takes in a List of `Class`es and a `Throwable` and returns true if any of the Classes in the list is a subclass of the throwable and false otherwise.

Jacoco shows the function with a green mark saying all braches covered. Yet in the table, it shows Coverage being only 75%

What's wrong here?

```
private fun isSubClass(exceptionList: List<Class<out Throwable>>, throwable: Throwable): Boolean {
        return exceptionList.any { throwable::class.isSubclassOf(it.kotlin) }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tested your method against an empty list, a matching exception and not matching. Report: 100% code coverage, 1 line of code. But your coverage picture shows 4 Lines for `isSubClass`. Is it the whole code in the picture?

Comment: `any` is acting like an `if` statement here: do your tests run both the `true` and the `false` cases? This is what "branches" refers to when it comes to code coverage.

Comment: @ocos Thanks for taking time to reply to my message. Yes 1 line of code. Just now I'm seeing Lines = 4 I'm equally puzzled why Lines = 4 is being shown here.